# read from file and use strtok() in c

Tags: c, strtok

can you help me? I am trying to read a string `123;342;543;36.6;calm` in a .txt file. And then use function `atoi()` for comparing my values. But the first I would like to use strtok(). I don't understand what is wrong with that , because I only works `printf("%s",str);` but I can't use `strtok()` correctly that's why I don't get my result.

CODE:

```
void printInfo()
{
    int i;
    FILE *out;
    char str[250];
    char sp[10]=";";
    char *istr;
    istr=strtok(str,sp);

    if ((out =fopen("test.txt","r"))==NULL)
        printf("Error open, file\n");
    else
    {
            fgets(str,250,out);
            printf("%s",str);
            while (istr != NULL)
            {
                printf("%s",istr);
                istr=strtok(NULL,sp);
            }
    }
   fclose(out);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first `strtok()` call is at the wrong place. It must be after the string `str` has received valid contents, i.e. after `fgets()`.

This would be easier, cleaner and safer to do with `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
istr=strtok(str,sp);
```

should be called after you read the data

Comment: Honest CC: You need to be a *little* more detailed; your grammar needs work too.